# as_json issue with include tables

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kriya_sessions
end

class KriyaSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in my users controller I'm trying like

```
def user_sessions
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users.as_json(include: [:kriya_sessions])
end
```

But in my response I don't see any kriya_sessions object in my user object. Can someone tell me where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def user_sessions
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users.as_json(include: :kriya_sessions)
end
```

This works for me. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, Sorry my code was working but I have a `serializable_hash` method in my user model which is overwriting this as_json(). What can I do to avoid calling serializable_hash method in model?

Comment: can you show me *serializable_hash* in your *User* model? BTW, as_json is just a thin wrapper around **serializable_hash**